# Simulating location China in iOS 7 to test per-app camera permissions

Tags: camera, geolocation, ios7

New in iOS7, users need to grant per-app permissions for microphone access.  This is worldwide.  In China, users also are prompted to grant per-app permissions for camera access.

How do I (not in China) test this? I want to be able to play with where I request this permission and how my app handles permission denied.

Thanks

Comment: Now that iOS 8 has added this to all countries this question is irrelevant.